# Getting a Persistent States Store to Handle Expiration

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is there any way with a persistent state store to allow for keys in a KeyValueStore to expire? I know there is a retention period in the persistentSessionStore, but it looks like that isn't KeyValue based.

Answer (score 0):

There is no expiration mechanism atm. There is Jira feature request for this though: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4212

What you can do it though, to register a punctuation and delete data manually. You would need to store the timestamp as part of the value though and scan the whole store to find old keys.